# Can't run nw (shared library) file for NWJS

Tags: nodejs, shared-library

In the NWJS docs http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started I need to run the `nw` file, but it is a shared library. Is there a way I can run a shared library? On windows I open `package.json` with `nw.exe`, and the docs seem to state that I need to open `package.json` with `nw`. What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install nwjs in your Ubuntu setup ? I just downloaded Nwjs stable 0.20 for Linux 64 bit, unpacked the archive, and tried : ./nw (without any parameters) and it started fine, showing a window mentioning Chromium and Node version. That is not a library, but a binary.

Comment: When I tried ./nw I got nw is not a directory. @albert_j

Comment: Here's how I tested after downloading and extracting the archive : ~/D/TEST233242434 $ cd nwjs-v0.20.0-linux-x64/
~/D/T/nwjs-v0.20.0-linux-x64 $ ./nw -h
No manual entry for nw   .... And ./nw simply loads this : https://i.imgur.com/ZxL8goY.png  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 here. Perhaps post the output of : ldd -v ./nw